# calling different URL based on button value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a button that calls a CFM page and it needs to pass a value depending on whether the user is activating or deactivating a record from the database. I'm struggling with how to pass the active/inactive value into jQuery. Below is the code I'm using, which only works one-way, that is from active to inactive.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#IsActive_1").click(function() {

    //cache the status div
        var status = $("#status");

        //let the user know the record is being updated
        status.html("<i>updating status...</i>");

    $("#IsActive_1").html('activate');

        //the status variable needs to be dynamic
        $.get("updateStatus.cfm?status=inactive", {}, function(res,code) {
        //show the result in plain HTML
        status.html(res);
    });

    });

});
</script>


<button id="IsActive_1"><cfif IsActive>deactivate<cfelse>activate</cfif></button><div id="status"></div>
```

Lastly, I would like to change the text displayed on the button to activate/deactivate based on the proper condition (activate after clicking deactivate and viceversa).

TIA

Comment: What does the user do to either activate or de-activate a record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an attr to the button, and based on it, send the variable.

```
<button id="IsActive_1" checked="checked">Deactivate</button>


    $("#IsActive_1").click(function() {
          var x = $(this);
          var isActive = x.attr('checked') != undefined;
          if (isActive)
            x.removeAttr('checked');
          else
            x.attr('checked', 'checked');
        //cache the status div
            var status = $("#status");

            //let the user know the record is being updated
            status.html("<i>updating status...</i>");

             x.html(isActive ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate');

            //the status variable needs to be dynamic
            $.get("updateStatus.cfm", { status : isActive ? 'inactive' : 'active' }, function(res,code) {
            //show the result in plain HTML
            status.html(res);
        });

        });
```